# Sum odds in integer N - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filter, sum

I'm trying to make a function that will calculate the sum of the odds in a N integer.

For example, if N = 5 => 1+3+5 = 9

Here is my attempt :

```
const n = 4

let arr = []
let i = 0
while (i < n) {
    i++
    arr.push(i)
}

console.log(arr)
```

This code return an array with all integers in N, that's ok.

Now I would like to filter the odds, then make the sum of it.
I tried different things without success.

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const calculateSum = (n) => {
  
  let sum = 0;

  // Start from 1 and increment by 2 (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, etc)
  for(let i = 1; i <= n; i+=2) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;

}
```

Comment: Nice logic. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `Array.reduce()` to get the desired result. We generate all integers from 1 to N using `Array.from()`, then use .reduce() to add any odd numbers to the sum (accumulator) value.

```js
function getSumOfOddNumbers(n) {
    return Array.from({length: n}, (v,k) => k + 1).reduce((sum, cur) => (cur % 2) ? sum + cur: sum, 0);
}

for(let n = 1; n < 10; n += 2) {  
    console.log(`Odd number sum from 1 to ${n}:`, getSumOfOddNumbers(n));
   }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ok, nice way to do it. I need to practice .reduce(). Thank you !

Comment: Oh yes, just a different approach. Either is good!